# Understading usage of functor composed with natural transformation in CT definitions

Tags: category-theory, functors, monads

I'm reading about [Monads on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)), I'm confused about these two defining diagrams.

> [image]

Where $T$ is the endofunctors $\mu: T^2 \to T$ and $\eta: 1_C \to T$. So, my question is, why is the two arrow in left diagram $T \mu $ and on the right diagram $\eta T$? Couldn't we just have $\mu$ only on left and $\eta$ only on right?

Answer (score 2):

No? $\mu$ runs $T^2\implies T$. To get a transformation $T^3\implies T^2$ you need to do *something* to $\mu$, and the two natural choices that work in general are the 'whiskered' transformations $\mu T$ and $T\mu$, defined via components $\mu_{TX}:T^3X=T^2(TX)\to T^2X$ and $T(\mu_X):T^3X=T(T^2X)\to T(TX)=T^2X$ respectively.

These two transformations are potentially different. The monad coherence diagrams say they agree after applying $\mu$, which is generally useful in computations and diagram chasing.

Comment: How on earth is $T(\mu_X)$ from $T^3X \to T^2X$ I don't get the domain choice at all

Comment: @SBrian I wrote $T^3X=T(T^2X),T^2X=T(TX)$ for a reason. $\mu_X:T^2X\to TX$ so, because $T$ is a functor, there is an arrow $T(\mu_X):T(T^2X)\to T(TX)$

Comment: I guess the point of confusion I had was how the functor changes both the domain and codomain

Comment: @SBrian Yes. If $f:a\to b$ is an arrow in a category $C$ and $F:C\to D$ is a functor, $F(f)$ will run $F(a)\to F(b)$. This is still true if $C=D$, as it is in the case of monads

Comment: What object and arrow are you taking for the case of the examples above? Or, are you not taking particular objects and considering the category as a whole with all the objects?

Comment: @SBrian I don't understand the question. "If $f:a\to b$ is an arrow..." is hardly an example, it's more part of the definition of functor. In the discussion of $\mu T$ and $T\mu$, it's self-explanatory what the objects are. When I write $\mu_{TX}:T^3X\to T^2X$ then it is an arrow with source $T^3X$ and target $T^2X$, that's what the notation means